# Trying to limit access to custom meta box without success

Tags: metabox

I have this meta box that I have added to my site:

```
// Assistant Editor Box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assistant_editor_box' );
function assistant_editor_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'assistant_editor_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Assistant Editor' ), // meta box title
        'assistant_editor_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'high' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );
}

function assistant_editor_cb( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'proofread', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Proofread: </label>';

    $assedit = array(
        1 => ' Yes ',
    );

    echo '<select name="proofread">';
    echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($assedit[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> No </option>';

    // output
    foreach ($assedit as $id => $text) {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadataeditass($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;


    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["proofread"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'proofread');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'proofread', $_REQUEST['proofread']);
    }

}
// END Assistant Editor Box
```

I want to limit access to it based on Capability. I tried the following code:

```
function remove_assistant_editor_box_meta() { 
   if (!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')){
       remove_meta_box( 'assistant_editor_box', 'post', 'side' );
   }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_assistant_editor_box_meta' );
```

Did not work, tried this as well:

```
function remove_assistant_editor_box_meta(){
    if(function_exists('assistant_editor_box') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts')){
        add_filter('assistant_editor_box', '__return_false');
    }   
}
add_action('init', 'remove_assistant_editor_box_meta');
```

According to the Wordpress documents, the first code should work, **what in the world am I doing wrong here**?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add the permission check to the `assistant_editor_box()` function around or before `add_meta_box()`?

Comment: I would not know how to be honest, do you?

Comment: Is the plugin creating the meta box your own? Or is it a 3rd-party plugin that may be updated and overwrite your edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @totels says, just apply the condition **when you add the box**, rather than trying to remove it later (FYI, it's not working because you call the removal on hooks that fire earlier!)

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assistant_editor_box' );
function assistant_editor_box() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) )
        add_meta_box(
            'assistant_editor_box',
            ...
        )
}
```